# Pass JVM arguments into an executable jar via spring boot gradle plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I want to pass JVM arguments into a bash script part of the executable jar so that the jar starts with specific configuration. Is there an easy way to do so via gradle spring boot plugin?

Comment: What do you mean by "a bash script part of the executable jar"?  Are you talking about a bash script that executes the jar, or something else?  The "part of the executable jar" bit makes me wonder if I understand the question or not.

Comment: If you package your fat jar as an executable, it will contain a bunch of bash commands prepended to the jar file itself. You just need to open that jar with any text editor and you'll see.

Comment: "it will contain a bunch of bash commands prepended to the jar " - That surprises me.  I don't think that happens by default.

Comment: Of course it's not a default behavior. You need to explicitly enable it. Otherwise you'll start your application via "java -jar ".